# Enumerating a NSArray of different objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello World!", [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"], nil];
for (id *object in array) {
 NSLog(@"Class name: %@", [object className]);
}
```

Given the above array of varying objects what is the proper way to fast enumerate thru them?  Using the above code I do see my log statement properly, but Xcode does complain with the following message

Invalid receiver type 'id*'  on my NSLog statement.

Comment: Xcode is the IDE, not the compiler. Currently, the compiler is GCC unless you've switched it to Clang.

Answer (score 10):

That should be:

```
for (id object in array) {
// ...
```

That is because `id` already is a pointer, see the [section on `id`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW3) in Apples [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) for details on it.